# Text with long shadow in Illustrator (or Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, text

Good afternoon, I'd like to recreate the text effect shown in the picture with Photoshop or Illustrator

[image]

How can I do to achieve this result?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why wasn't it successful?

Comment: I've tried to "play" with the 3D effect in Illustrator but I didn't manage to achieve this result of a strong long shadow and "fake 3D"

Comment: have you serched for "long shadow"? There are plenty of tutorials everywhere

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator, type some bold text, and apply a black stroke to the letters, and a different coloured fill for some letters.

Do *Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel*

Change the length of the black part by changing the Extrude Depth.

Example

[image]